# CSS acting differently in localhost

Tags: css, django, localhost, django-runserver

I'm working on a project. So first, i started with front-end. And then after finishing that, i loaded all the files in django app and started the localhost. But suddenly everything seems to be bigger. Most of the padding, margin, font-size, changes from small to big

I have disabled cache, recoded all the static linkings

1.front end designed locally is the first image.

2.frond end after loading into localhost is the second image

Why is this happening, is there any solution for this. Do I have to redesign all on the perspective of localhost AGAIN?

[image: Front-end designed locally]
[image: Front-end after loading into localhost]

Comment: Are you sure all the css files are loaded? If you're also using third party css libs (bootstrap et al.) make sure the versions are same.

Comment: yes, i have loaded, and there is no css libs usage

Comment: Try reloading the page with cache disabled. `Dev tools panel > Network tab > Disable cache`

Comment: Please share full code

Comment: @xyres It doesn't help though but, when i was going to do that, the console was showing an error   

"Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8000/style1.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
"

Comment: How are you serving the css file? I'm guessing from a custom view? You ought to let django serve the static files. It will take care of appropriate mime (content-type) headers. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

Comment: @xyres It was mistake while debugging, but now the problem still exist and there is no errors in console